# Html creating a dropdown on more rows

Tags: html, css

I have built an dropdown with more dropdown links inside. It`s like a dropdown inside a dropdown. I have a problem when i want to place the second dropdowns in more rows or columns.

Here is the Css i have used to create the containers for the dropdown menu

```
.container{
  position: relative;

} 
div.container ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
div.container ul li
{
    background-color:silver;
    width:100px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline:black solid 1px;

}
div.container ul li:hover
{
    background-color:red;


}
div.container ul ul
{
    display:none;

}
div.container ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;

}
div.container ul ul ul
{
    margin-left:100px;
    top:0px;
    position: absolute;

}
```

and html:

```
    <div class=" container ">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Magazin</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Pc</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

I want it to look like

```
                Magazin
Mouse here->    PC         Home Home Home
                Laptop     Home Home Home
```

something like this.Please help.Thanks :)

Comment: If I understood it correct, you are looking for a nested dropdown list where the lists will open to right of the dropdown list item. Am I correct? Please confirm if this is what you are looking for in plain HTML, CSS : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: Hi. I don`t want it to be like that..i want the dropdown look like a table..not only 1 row or only 1 column..something to open like a 3x3 table or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.
Let me know if this works for you.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;

} 
div.container ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
div.container ul li
{
    background-color:silver;
    width:100px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline:black solid 1px;

}
div.container ul li:hover
{
    background-color:red;


}
div.container ul ul
{
    display:none;

}
div.container ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;

}
div.container ul ul ul
{
    margin-left:100px;
    top:0px;
    position: absolute;

}
#pc{
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:40px;
 }
 #laptop{
   position:fixed;
  margin-top:60px;
 }
```

```html
    <div class=" container ">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Magazin</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Pc</a>
                    <ul id = "pc">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li><a href="#">laptop</a>
                   <ul id ="laptop">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    
                    </ul>
                    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: it works for me but it`s not what i was looking for. I wanted to expand 1 dropdown in a box with menu items going like 2x2 or 3x3 like when i touch the PC it should expand in something like home home home and home home home on the next row

Comment: Edit:
As i can see in the snippet here it looks good..that`s what i want but in my html page is not going on the next row automatically..that`s what i want to do like to skip the row when i want and put it on the next row..something like what <br> does

Comment: I figured it out. I did use a max-width in div.container ul ul ul class.